# Get-AzKeyVaultSecret can't read secret value in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault, powershell-az-module

I'm not able to read the value of one of my secrets in Key Vault. I'm logged in with my Azure account and I have full permission to the selected Key Vault.

I'm able to retrieve a list of available secrets using the following command:

```
$keyVaultValue = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'name-of-key-vault')
```

And then see the content when I write:

```
Write-Output $keyVaultValue
```

But when I ask for a specific key it just returns null:

```
$keyVaultValue = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'name-of-key-vault' -Name 'my-secret-name').SecretValueText
```

I've checked the name and subscription ID and everything is correct. I can easily read the value from the portal, but no from powershell on my Windows PC.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SecretValueText` is deprecated, You can use the following syntax the retrieve the value as plain text:

```
$keyVaultValue = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'name-of-key-vault' -Name 'my-secret-name'
$keyVaultValue.SecretValue | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText
```

More information and examples can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-5.4.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-5.0.0#example-5--get-the-plain-text-value-of-the-current-version-of-a-specific-secret).

Comment: "ConvertFrom-SecureString : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AsPlainText'"

Comment: 'AsPlainText' was added in PowerShell 7.0. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring

Comment: Is it still up to date? Im getting "ConvertFrom-SecureString: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'SecureString' because it is null."

Comment: Try this one. This will work
$secretText = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVault -Name $CertSecret -AsPlainText

Write-Host "Secret Value: $secretText"

Answer (score 4):

If you want to show all key-vault secrets name and their key values then you can use this in powershell

```
$secrets=Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'key-vault-name'
$secrets | % {Write-Output "$($_.name) $($(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $_.VaultName -Name $_.Name).SecretValue | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText)" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add some more recent and easier ways to achieve this.
With the latest versions of Az, you can just add **-AsPlainText** parameter after the command to get the secret value directly.

```
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVaultName -Name $SecretName -AsPlainText
```

Here is a full usage example of getting a certificate from the key vault and saving it as a pfx file using the same cmdlet.

```
{... Skipping code ...}
$CertificateSecretValue = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVautlName -Name $CertificateSecretName -AsPlainText

# Decode the base64-encoded PFX
$CertificateSecretBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($CertificateSecretValue)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($PfxCertFilePath, $CertificateSecretBytes)
# {... Skipping code ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we use *-AsPlainText* in *Get-AzKeyVaultSecret*, then it will work.

```
$secretText = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVault -Name $CertSecret -AsPlainText
Write-Host "Secret Value: $secretText"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function:

```
function GetSecretValue
{
    param(
        [String]$keyvaultName,
        [String]$secretName
    )

    Write-Host "Retrieving secret $secretName from $keyvaultName... " -NoNewline
    if ((Get-Command Get-AzKeyVaultSecret).ParameterSets.Parameters.Name -contains "AsPlainText")
    {
        # Newer Get-AzKeyVaultSecret version requires -AsPlainText parameter 
        $secretValue = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultName -Name $secretName -AsPlainText
    }
    else
    {
        $secretValue = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultName -Name $secretName).SecretValueText
    }
    Write-Host "ok"
    return $secretValue
}
```

Usage example:

```
$keyVaultValue = GetSecretValue "name-of-key-vault" "my-secret-name"
```