# Retrieve the secret value from Azure Keyvault with Az.KeyVault Powershell module

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

With [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-cli) one uses
`az keyvault secret show`
to read the secret value.

How is it done with [Azure Powershell/Az.KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/)?

I have tried `GetAzKeyVaultSecret` but it returns the record without the secret value.

Comment: I think you mean `Az Cli` rather than `AzureRM` ?

Comment: You are looking for this command: `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-6.3.0.

Comment: You need to use the `-AsPlainText` argument https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-6.3.0#example-5--get-the-plain-text-value-of-the-current-version-of-a-specific-secret

Comment: @Thomas Please write your comment as an answer. Also add that `-Name` or similar must be present because just `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName vaultname -AsPlainText` does not work; it cannot output a list of secretvalues.

Comment: LosManos, good to here that it worked :-) @kobulloc wrote a nice answer so I don't think I need to write another one. Just happy to help :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Get-AzKeyVaultSecret` in the [Azure Az PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell#retrieve-a-secret-from-key-vault) is the equivalent of `az keyvault secret show` in the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-cli#retrieve-a-secret-from-key-vault):

**PowerShell Az Module**

```
$keyVaultValue = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "kobulloc-keyvaultAZPS" -Name "ExampleAZPSPassword"
$keyVaultValue.SecretValue | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText
```

[image]

**CLI**

```
az keyvault secret show --name "ExampleCLIPassword" --vault-name "kobulloc-keyvaultCLI" --query "value"
```

[image]

**References:**

- [Quickstart: Set and retrieve a secret from Azure Key Vault using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell)
- [Quickstart: Set and retrieve a secret from Azure Key Vault using Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-cli)
- [Get-AzKeyVaultSecret can't read secret value in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825151/get-azkeyvaultsecret-cant-read-secret-value-in-powershell)

Comment: `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName vaultname -AsPlainText -Name secretname` is enough, no need for `ConvertFrom-SecureString`.

Comment: `-AsPlainText` seems to be ignored when listing secrets.

Comment: To get all secretvalues for a subset of secrets: `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName vaultname | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*cosmos*"} | Select-Object -Property Name, @{ label='SecretValue'; expression={Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName vaultname -Name $_.Name -AsPlainText} }` This way it we can list every secret "having to do with cosmos" and, for instance, verify they are all using the same key.

Comment: this did not work for me, this did:


`$keyVaultValue = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "kobulloc-keyvaultAZPS" -Name "ExampleAZPSPassword" -AsPlainText`