# Get a secret value from azure keyvault using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault

I am trying to extract a secret from the Azure key vault. I am using the below code but cannot extract it and an empty string for secret value is coming as output.

```
$AzureTenantId  = "####"       
$AzureApplicationId = "####"    
$AzureApplicationSecret = "#####"    
$SecuredApplicationSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString "$AzureApplicationSecret" -AsPlainText -Force  
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AzureApplicationId ,$SecuredApplicationSecret)  
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $AzureTenantId -ServicePrincipal $keyVaultName = "####" $secretName = "####"   
$Secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $secretName   
Write-Host "Secret Object: $Secret"  
Write-Host "Secret Value: $($Secret.SecretValueText)"
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
Secret Object: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.PSKeyVaultSecret
Secret Value:
```

What changes I need to make in the code to extract the secret value from the keyvault?

Answer (score 0):

Check these links:

1. [Example 5: Get the plain text value of the current version of a specific secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-11.1.0#example-5-get-the-plain-text-value-of-the-current-version-of-a-specific-secret)
2. [Retrieve a secret from Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell#retrieve-a-secret-from-key-vault)

Maybe you need to add `-AsPlainText` parameter

```
$SecretValue = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $secretName -AsPlainText
```

Or check this solution: [Retrieve the secret value from Azure Keyvault with Az.KeyVault Powershell module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68989621/retrieve-the-secret-value-from-azure-keyvault-with-az-keyvault-powershell-module)

```
$Secret.SecretValue | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText
```

Comment: Yes I had added -AsPlainText as well but it did not work

Comment: @user10434309 check the third solution with `ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText` operation